# Pagination in Google cloud endpoints + Datastore + Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, pagination, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I want to return a List of "Posts" from an endpoint with optional pagination.
I need 100 results per query.
The Code i have written is as follows, it doesn't seem to work.
I am referring to an example at [Objectify Wiki](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#cursors)

Another option i know of is using `query.offset(100);`
But i read somewhere that this just loads the entire table and then ignores the first 100 entries which is not optimal.

I guess this must be a common use case and an optimal solution will be available.

```
public CollectionResponse<Post> getPosts(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursor,User auth) throws OAuthRequestException {
        if (auth!=null){

            Query<Post> query = ofy().load().type(Post.class).filter("isReviewed", true).order("-timeStamp").limit(100);

            if (cursor!=null){
                query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
                log.info("Cursor received :" + Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
            } else {
                log.info("Cursor received : null");
            }

            QueryResultIterator<Post> iterator = query.iterator();

            for (int i = 1 ; i <=100 ; i++){
                if (iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next();
                else break;
            }

            log.info("Cursor generated :" + iterator.getCursor());

            return CollectionResponse.<Post>builder().setItems(query.list()).setNextPageToken(iterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()).build();

        } else throw new OAuthRequestException("Login please.");
    }
```

This is a code using Offsets which seems to work fine.

```
@ApiMethod(
            name = "getPosts",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET
    )
    public CollectionResponse<Post> getPosts(@Nullable @Named("offset") Integer offset,User auth) throws OAuthRequestException {
        if (auth!=null){

            if (offset==null) offset = 0;

            Query<Post> query = ofy().load().type(Post.class).filter("isReviewed", true).order("-timeStamp").offset(offset).limit(LIMIT);

            log.info("Offset received :" + offset);
            log.info("Offset generated :" + (LIMIT+offset));

            return CollectionResponse.<Post>builder().setItems(query.list()).setNextPageToken(String.valueOf(LIMIT + offset)).build();

        } else throw new OAuthRequestException("Login please.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to assign the query:

```
query = query.startAt(cursor);
```

Objectify's API uses a functional style. `startAt()` does not mutate the object.

Comment: Is this way more efficient than using offsets ?

Comment: Yes, dramatically so

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Remove your `for` loop -- not sure why it is there. But just iterate through your list and build out the list of items that you want to send back. You should stick to the iterator and not force it for 100 items in a loop.
2. Next, once you have iterated through it, use the `iterator.getStartCursor()` as the value of the cursor.

Comment: The `iterator.getStartCursor()` method is not available in Objectify.

Comment: I want a way to avoid loops in my methods altogether. The reason i added is just to generate that next page cursor. I want to get rid of it.
Eventually i want to rely on Memcache to improve performance. So a Single Query like the one with offsets would perform much better.

Comment: You can't use cursors without an iterator because a list (obviously) does not expose an iterator. You will have to use a loop for cursor queries. There's an example on how to use cursors here: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#cursors